# What is the 'scientific-productivity' tag supposed to be for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the tag wiki excerpt for [scientific-productivity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-productivity) read:

> Queries and Discussion related to either qualitative or quantitative productivity of a scientist/scholar.

The full tag wiki then goes on to say:

> The term scientific productivity often refers to attempts on quantifying to scientific impact of an individual’s research publications. There are a number of indices to quantify impact of a scientist in their respective fields, by means of number of papers produced, etc.; like h-index, g-index etc.

So OK, it's about measuring the impact of a scientist/scholar. Indeed, some of the questions in this tag are consistent with this meaning - notably, those that are [also tagged](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-productivity+bibliometrics) with [bibliometrics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliometrics).

However, more of the questions with this tag are about productivity in the sense of "tips for being more efficient as a scientist." For example,

- [How to efficiently read mathematically and theoretically dense books in STEM fields?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-to-efficiently-read-mathematically-and-theoretically-dense-books-in-stem-fie)
- [How does one keep herself updated with new research without forgetting older results?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/how-does-one-keep-herself-updated-with-new-research-without-forgetting-older-res)
- [How to avoid procrastination during the research phase of my PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/how-to-avoid-procrastination-during-the-research-phase-of-my-phd)

Finally, some are about neither of these things, like

- [Charging graduate students for printing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11061/charging-graduate-students-for-printing)
- [How to prevent physical/psychological health side effects of workaholism in academia and research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26779/how-to-prevent-physical-psychological-health-side-effects-of-workaholism-in-acad)
- [Can one be average in academics but great in research at same time in PhD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/can-one-be-average-in-academics-but-great-in-research-at-same-time-in-phd)

It's not clear to me whether there is another meaning of [scientific-productivity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-productivity) that I'm not getting, that applies to these and similar questions, or whether they are just tagged incorrectly.

I am concerned about this ambiguity, because it does not seem like people searching for questions about "measuring the impact of a scientist/scholar" are also looking for questions on "becoming more efficient".

What should be done about the [scientific-productivity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-productivity) tag?

Answer (score 1):

I say **burninate**.  I agree that [bibliometrics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliometrics) seems to cover the intended use.

I'm also not really happy about its name.  "Scientific" leaves out vast swaths of the academic community, which tend to be under-represented here to start with.  We don't need to further alienate our colleagues in the arts, humanities, and other fields.

Comment: Do you think we need a tag for the unintended use, "tips for being more efficient as a scholar"? Or do you think an existing tag already covers these?

Comment: Maybe simply [tag:productivity]?  Or is that too vague?  A couple of them may be covered by [tag:work-life-balance].

Comment: **burninate** would remove the tag entirely from every question it's on. If we *should* have a "productivity" tag, then the course of action would be not to burninate, but to rename "scientific-productivity" to "productivity" (and then retag the questions where it isn't appropriate). I'm not sure which approach you're advocating, can you edit your answer to clarify?

Comment: @ff254: Well, to put it this way, I don't think a tag named [tag:scientific-productivity] with a purpose as currently described in the wiki needs to exist.  Perhaps a tag called [tag:productivity] should exist and be applied to some questions that are currently mistagged [tag:scientific-productivity] but I am not sure about that.  If it is more convenient to rename rather than burninating and letting the potential [tag:productivity] be gradually added to those questions that need it, that is fine too.

Comment: Rename (aka "merge") would instantly and silently change every existing instance of [tag:scientific-productivity] to [tag:productivity]. This is very different from just removing the tag altogether, because it preserves the information that *somebody* thought these questions are somehow related to "scientific-productivity"

Comment: I would have to become Trogdor to burninate.